# Is it possible to pass an unset variable to a function or otherwise validate forms without isset()?

Tags: php, json, validation

I've got a project that passes JSON between the frontend and the backend. So, the frontend PHP would generate the statement `{ "command" : "getuser", "parameters" : { "userid" : 1 } }` and send it to the backend. The backend then executes

```
if ($command == 'getuser') {
  validate($parameters['userid']);
  if ($this->valid) { <<get the user>> }
}
```

Validate checks the variable and sets `$this->valid`. It creates an error message if necessary. I want to create an error message in case the front end passes in `{ "command" : "getuser", "parameters" : "" }`. In this case, `$parameters['userid']` is never set, and validate() will complain that it was passed an unset variable.

I've come up with two solutions. The first solution is to set `$parameters['userid'] = "unset"` before loading in the JSON, and then check for it in the validator. The other solution is to use

```
if (isset($parameters['userid'])) { 
  validate($parameters['userid']);
} 
else { 
  echo("Error"); }
```

It'd be nice if `validate()` could figure out on its own whether or not the variable is there. Is there a more elegant way I should be doing things?

Comment: How does this magic `validate()` function work?  What's it supposed to be doing?

Comment: It's making sure that the form input was correct before it executes the rest of the function. So in this case, it's making sure that no non-alphanumeric characters were entered, that the string isn't blank, and that the string was of a certain length.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In short, no. The error happens as, rather than after, validate() is called so there is no way for it to intercept that.

It sounds like a better solution would be to have a validateUser() function that is passed in the whole $parameters variable then does the check you're looking for against the 'user_id'. This allows you to to further separate your concerns (validation, versus response).

Comment: Seems like passing the whole array is the way to go. I was trying to avoid that step of a nested if(), but it seems to be inevitable.

Answer (score 0):

If you want this style of code, you could pass arg to function by reference
If not, try to use this validate($parameters, 'userid');

Answer (score 0):

You would have to pass `$parameters` into `validate` and let it check if `userid` was there and if not create the error message.